# Performance wise do or don't add width and height to an img tag

Tags: html

**I know this question is asked before.**
Most of them are 5-6 years old, so at the latest browsers do you add or don't you add the height and width of the original img size?

```
 <img class="stars-img" src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/star-128.png" height="128px" width="128px">
```

or

```
 <img class="stars-img" src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/star-128.png">
```

*The resizing of the img will still be done with css so it's not about separation styling from the html*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr**: it's no impact on loading time.

The benefit in adding the width and height to the image tag is that the browser will place floating text according to the image size and avoid "jumping" the text if the pictures is ready with loading.

So it makes sense to add the dimensions if you know them. If you're simply adding dummy values, than it's useless and should not be done.

**Speed wise** it's practically no impact. A *reasonable* `width="1000px" height="800px"` has 29 Bytes.

With a downstream of 24.0 Mbit/s that's a delay of [9.667 **micro**seconds](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=29%20Bytes%20%2F%2024%20Mbit%2Fs%20) (in this time, light travels 2898 meters). With a 56kbit modem, it's 4.143 milliseconds per picture.

Even if you have 10.000 pictures on one page, the delay would only be 96.67 milliseconds (41.43 seconds with 56kbit). And it would cost a lot more time to load all the images.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still going to style with CSS, is there any benefit in adding it in the first place?

If you're concerned about performance, you'd be better off having the images as the size required on upload, so that you're not loading bigger images than you need.

Comment: sometimes the size of the img needs to be different when you're on a desktop compared to a mobile

Comment: So why not use media queries in CSS?

Comment: of course i will use media queries but that's the css styling, i'm wondering if performance wise it's better to tell the browser the original height and width in the html

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the size of the imgages if possible, so that the browser knows how much space the image will need. That prevents the browser from needing to move elements around to make room for images that appear.

Normally it won't matter if you set the size in the HTML or in the CSS, but setting it in the CSS may allow you to specify the same size for multiple images. Also, as the CSS is cached it makes sense to move styling there to reduce the HTML size.